# Printing Gantt charts

Tags: ms-project, gantt

When I try to print my Gantt schedule, it hides a bunch of my information rows. How can I fix this? See the comparison between actual Gantt and print preview below:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What version are you using? Does this happen every time with every project? FWIW I am not able to replicate with project 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting **Print Entire Project** and in **Page Setup** select **Fit to:** x number of pages.

[image: screenshot]